# Is Google App Indexing page view recording work locally?

Tags: android, google-play, deep-linking, android-app-indexing, google-search-platform

I'm integrating google app indexing API. Currently I record page views which makes my Google Now search autocomplete queries and suggest my app's activities. But I wonder if it's the result of local history or based on my applications user base activities. Say if many people already use my app and send page views using google app indexing API will it make  autocompletion to be suggested for the users who install my app at the first time?

Answer (score 3):

The autocompletions are based an individual's usage history for that particular user.  So users that install your app for the first time will not see deep linked autocompletions -- until using your app.  However, if the new user starts typing the *name* of your app, she should see your app appear in the autocompletions right away.